# zsh - How do I make local variables available to inner functions that are not defined with 'eval'?

Tags: zsh, variable, function

I have a zsh function that looks like this:

```bsh
outer_func () {
    local LOCAL_VAR='test'
    inner_func () {
        echo "${LOCAL_VAR}"
    }
}
```

where `$LOCAL_VAR` is not available to `inner_func`.

I know that I can use `eval` to define `inner_func` so that it can access the value of `$LOCAL_VAR`, I wonder if there's another way to do it?

Edit: test on zsh 5.8:

```
$ cat test.zsh
outer_func () {
    local LOCAL_VAR='test'
    inner_func () {
        echo "${LOCAL_VAR}"
    }
}

echo 'executing outer_func'
outer_func
echo 'executing inner_func'
inner_func

$ ./test.zsh
executing outer_func
executing inner_func

$
```

Edit 2: Clarification: I actually use `outer_func` to set variables to a series of `inner_func`s which are essential for the `inner_func`s to work, and after the definition of `outer_func`, I need to call the `inner_func`s.

Comment: Using zsh 5.8, using your example `LOCAL_VAR` is visible within `inner_func` if I call `inner_func` from `outer_func`

Comment: @AndyDalton I'm using zsh 5.8 but it doesn't seem to work on my Mac. :( See the screenshot above.

Comment: @TeddyC It doesn't work since you're not calling `inner_func` from within `outer_func`, like Andy said.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks for the info. What if I need to call `inner_func` directly, not from within `outer_func`? (See Edit 2)

Comment: Whenever you run `inner_func`, it's going to use a variable named `LOCAL_VAR` that is in scope (if one exists).  I think `eval` is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an "inner function" in Zsh. What your `outer_func` does is, each time it gets called, it creates a normal function `inner_func` that is publicly available (and which will overwrite any existing function called `inner_func`). However, your `outer_func` does not actually *call* `inner_func`. It merely creates it.

What you probably want is this:

```bsh
outer_func () {
  local LOCAL_VAR='test'
  inner_func
}

inner_func () {
  echo "${LOCAL_VAR}"
}
```

Then, when you call `outer_func`, the result will be that `inner_func` echoes `test`.

---

PS: You don’t need to use a local variable there. You can just use [positional parameters](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters) instead:

```bsh
outer_func() {
  inner_func 'test'
}

inner_func() {
  print - "$1"
}
```

Comment: @TeddyC Does this answer your question?